# Resolve SPFieldUserValue by Email

Tags: powershell, claims

We need to insert a bulk data from MS Excel into SharePoint lists. We committed this using Powershell. Almost everything straightforward, until we found a stoper with People columns.

From Excel people info are comming something like: `Claire@mycompany.com`, but SharePoint requires a valid `SPFieldUserValue`.

If I tried this: (it fails)

```
$item["MyPerson"] = $excelRow.MyPerson # this not works because is an Email.
```

I need something like:

```
$userValue = FindUserValueByEmail -email $excelRow.MyPerson
$item["MyPerson"] = $useValue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using **SSOM**, if so you probably also have a `$web` object for the SPWeb, and so you could try:

```
$user = $web.EnsureUser($excelRow.MyPerson)
$item["MyPerson"] = $user.ID
```

I don't think you need to assign an actual `SPFieldUserValue` object, but if you have to try this:

```
$item["MyPerson"] = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($web, $user.ID, $user.LoginName)
```